# How to get string height using width and font size?

Tags: ios, string, swift, height

I need to know string height so I can set cell height. The problem is I am getting string asynchronous, and I need to know cell Height before creating collection view. And I need this to work with different languages (special characters).

String will be in a label inside the cell. I had some of my solutions, but one did not work with other languages, and the other did work but didnt get the real heigth.

Answer (score 1):

```
    CGRect rect =[yourLabeltextString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(yourLabel.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) 
                 options:(NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin) 
              attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17]} 
                 context:nil];
  CGFloat height=rect.height;
```

Use the code above, and change the attributes to the one you prefered.You can get the height of your String.

Answer (score 0):

try this function and i hope it will help you :

```
- (CGFloat)calculateHeightForLabel:(UILabel *)label
{
    CGRect frame = label.frame;
    CGSize size = [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];
    return size.height;
}
```

Comment: one question, I am not that great with Objective C, what is FLT_MAX

Comment: FLT_MAX is the maximum value of a float

Comment: before to call this function on the label you set the test to that label or not ??

Comment: what do you mean by setting the test on that label? I rewrote this for swift, initialized the label with frame, inserted the text and call this function, printed the height it returned, but it was too small, so it worked but it didnt get me the right heigth

Comment: set the numberOfLines = 0 for your label before calling this function

Comment: yes, I did that too, ill put the code in the edit sometime tonight, sorry for trouble, you did help me understand few things that I did not know before, but for this situation it does not get the right heigth

Answer (score 0):

use it o Swift 5

```
extension UILabel {
    func calculateHeight() -> CGFloat {
        let size = self.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        return size.height
    }
}
```